# What is causing this "Cannot convert type" error in Swift?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I want to call a simple api and return the struct of JSON returned from server. I am using alamofire to achieve this.

This is my function

```
func loginUser(user_name: String, password: String, callBack:(Login) -> Void){
    let parameters: Parameters = ["user_name":  user_name,"password": password];
    let urlString=serverURL+"login.php";
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                switch(status) {
                case 200:
                    guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                        //error handling
                        return
                    }
                    if let login: Login = response.result.value {
                        callBack(login)
                    } else {
                        callBack(Login(user_id: 0, status:0))
                    }
                default:
                    print("HTTP Error : \(status)")
                    callBack(Login(user_id: 0, status:0))
                }
            }
    }
}

struct Login {
  let user_id: Int
  let status: Int
}
```

This line is generating a "cannot convert type" error.

```
if let login: Login = response.result.value {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `response.result.value` is either `[String : Any]` or `Array`, you can't just cast it to `Login` type and expect it to work

Comment: @mag_zbc i have added the login struct, how do i get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mag_zbc commented `response.result.value` is either `[String : Any]` or `Array`.

So first you need to cast them to respective type like suppose it's `[String : Any]` you can cast it as shown below:

```
if let response = response.result.value as? [String : Any] {
    //here you will get your dictionary
}
```

Now next thing you need to do is you need to take out the values from your `response` object which you can do by accessing the values from the keys from your `response` object which will look like:

```
let user_id = response["userid_key"] as? Int ?? 0
let status = response["status_key"] as? Int ?? 0
```

This way you will get `user_id` and `status` from your `response` object and then last step will be to set that data into your struct like shown below:

```
let login = Login(user_id: user_id, status: status)
```

Now you can set your callback with `callBack(login)`

and your final code will look like:

```
if let response = response.result.value as? [String : Any] {

    let user_id = response["userid_key"] as? Int ?? 0
    let status = response["status_key"] as? Int ?? 0

    let login = Login(user_id: user_id, status: status)

    callBack(login)
}
```